# Unable to update a custom field through process builder

Tags: apex, community, workflow, process-builder

I'm new to sfdc i got a requirement like there is standard field called probability% in opportunity.whenever if user updates probability field based on the value of this field a custom field forecast will be updated.

for ex: 
if value is more than 70 forecast will be yes or otherwise forecast will be no.

i had tried to do this by process builder but i don't where i had gone to wrong side.it only checks one condition called NO i think the condition is not checked for reference:

[image]

But i try to create workflow with same condition it works fine.But the problem is i have to create two workflow's for this requirement.

If i ask wrong question don't put down votes.

Comment: Haven't tested this exact scenario, but with percentage fields 70% would usually be 0.7, not 70 in your criteria conditions.  Also, does this need to be process builder, or would a formula field be an easier option?

Comment: Thanks @Alex McDonald i know we can do this with formula fields but i didn't create field this time because already custom field field is  available.So,i don't want to change to any datatype or to create a new field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@AlexMcDonald beat me to this while I was editing the Process but yes, probabilities must be expressed as decimals.

Note the other improvements in documentation of the Process (decisions should be expressed as decisions - here I used math notation but more normally it would be `isForecastable?` if the conditions are complex; actions should be imperatives)

[image]